# Can python-mode correct incorrect indentations?

Tags: python, emacs

Are there commands in python-mode (under EMacs) that can intelligently automatically detect and correct incorrect indentations?
For example, detect correct three spaces to four, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In `python-mode.el` there's a `py-indent-region`. I just tried it in a simple situations -- and it worked.

Comment: And it's bound to `^C <TAB>` by default.

Answer (score 1):

See also in menu Python/Checks

It offers commands to run known tools resp. bundles of them like pychecker, pylint, pep8, flake8, pyflakes

Make sure these backends are intalled, run "pip install pylint" for example.